# How to turn off autocompletion for numbers (and numbers only) in company-mode in spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, completion, company-mode, auto-complete-mode

When typing a number in spacemacs all kind of numbers are being suggested. I can autocomplete them with enter. I like this behaviour in the case I'm typing words (made up of letters). But I don't want this behaviour when I'm typing numbers.

Often I have to type a number at the end of a line. So for instance, when I want the number 10 but type enter in order to go to the next line, the 10 I type expands to 1001004005438142.

[image: example of a number being suggested when typing 10]

To avoid the 10 being expanded, I can type a space and after that an enter. That's the way I handle this at this moment.

However I just don't want numbers to automatically expand.

What functions or strings can I put into my `.spacemacs` (or `init.el`) to prevent numbers, and only numbers, from being suggested (and consequently being expanding when I type enter)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be as simple as:

```
(setq company-dabbrev-char-regexp "[A-z:-]")
```

I got this far by studying this q&a: [How can I prevent company-mode completing non-English chars?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36856/how-can-i-prevent-company-mode-completing-non-english-chars)

Comment: I still worry a bit about the regex I used here, since I don't know if it matches every word/expression that I want to be suggested...

Answer (score 2):

```
(push (apply-partially #'cl-remove-if
                       (lambda (c) (string-match-p "\\`[0-9]+\\'" c)))
      company-transformers)
```

The above code snippet is copied from the discussion at [How to let company-dabbrev ignore numbers analysis](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues/358)

Comment: Yes, this is the best answer, though I would delete the ending `\\;` anchor so that anything that starts with a number is exempt from completion.

Answer (score 1):

When this drop-down menu for numbers completion appears, typically the mode-line would show the company backend which is causing this completion. You can remove this backend from the list 'company-backends.

E.g. if company-dabbrev is doing it,

```
(delete 'company-dabbrev company-backends)
```

Alternatively, you could prevent company from completing without your consent by setting company-idle-delay to a large number. Mine is

```
(setq company-idle-delay 999999)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't want to lose company-dabbrev in its entirety, since (as far as I understand) it is responsible for autocompletion of the words previously used in the buffer.

Comment: OK, are you sure that dabbrev backend is causing the numbers drop down appearance ?

Comment: Yes, it is, since, changing the company-dabbrev-char-regexp changes the drop down behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered the same irritation.  The best answer is to stop it at the dabbrev level, not company-mode.  This works with cofu and other completion libraries as well:

```
(setq dabbrev-abbrev-skip-leading-regexp "[0-9]\\|\\$\\|\\*\\|/\\|=")
```

The only relevant bit is the first alternative with [0-9], causing dabbrev to forego completion when there is a digit at the beginning of the word to be completed.