# How can I prevent company-mode completing non-English chars?

Tags: company-mode, dabbrev

i tried these codes before,
but none of them works for me .
how can i edit this to achieve my goal.

[image]

Comment: Please use code blocks instead of images.

Answer (score 2):

happily got the answer from author of company-mode

> It's company-dabbrev-char-regexp, not -abbrev-.

Comment: Or even `dabbrev-abbrev-char-regexp` (which is what your image shows).